# Can I mock db calls which are normally running on docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am new at rails. I started in a company whose only rails developer just left. They ask me to write unit tests. Problem is application works on docker. I want to mock db with factory_bot on my local computer without running on docker. When I run test it gives error that it can not find the table. It is normal because there isn't any db working locally. I want to mock that db calls without creating any db locally. Is it possible

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
Could not find table

Comment: `there isn't any db working locally` -> but your project source code (locally) contains db schema, right ? i think you could try to run `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:setup` to setup db on local.

Answer (score 0):

By best practices, you should have a local DB to run tests. If you have local DB server, to setup it to run tests pretty simple: `rails db:test:prepare`